# Move files between S3 and multiple EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm trying to find an efficient way to move files between AWS S3 buckets and multiple EC2 servers.  Essentially what I want is an orchestration server looping through the files in an S3 bucket moving them to different EC2 servers for processing.  The orchestration server will then record (in redis/Elasticache) each individual file so that none of them are missing.  All the files are sequenced.  The sequence number is contained within the file name.

Unfortunately, I only know Node.js as a scripting language.  I can use nodejs Knox library to get the files, but I don't want to load the file onto the orchestration server as this is unnecessary, I want to push the file to another EC2 instance.  What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/details/) to process the files from your S3 bucket. It can run at certain events happening on S3 - like a new file was created in your S3 bucket. And you can write the code in node.js - AWS Lambda will call a node.js function where you get the parameters of the event that just happened. 
Then on your EC2 instances you can write an api in node.js and put it under an [Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/). This way you can push the file for processing from your AWS Lambda function to your Elastic Load Balancer so it will be processed by your instances.
This is pretty simple to build and easy to scale:Lambda is fully managed by AWS, so you don't need to worry about any infrastructure. While your instances should be easy to scale automatically for example based on metrics from your load balancer. 
You can also have a flow for your files that fail to process, the api on your instances can do something when they receive a wrong file - like put it back in a separate bucket on S3, send an email etc. 
For your Elasticache Redis server you should be able to access it both from your AWS Lambda function and from your EC2 instances, so you can get and set there whatever you need.

Comment: That sounds really good.  The problem is I am in Australia and Lambda isn't available down under.  I don't think I can start using a US or Europe based data centre.

Comment: I see it is available in the Tokyo region, this is the closest to you. You can still have your EC2 instances under a ELB on Sydney and the AWS Lamba to run on Tokyo. Only if you want to add a Redis server with Elasticache that would be accessible only under the same region. Also you can try talking to your account manager see if there are some plans for adding Lambda to Sydney region.